# Accessing SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a problem in the LiveWallpaper app (my first) I am developing.
Consider 2 classes: `LiveWallpaperService` and `LiveWallpaperSettings`.
`LiveWallpaperSettings` extends `PreferencyActivity`. Example data representing 
the preferences selected by the user, for example a `boolean displaySprite` (true=> display the sprite on the screen, false do not display) are saved/persisted via `SharedPreferences` in `LiveWallpaperSettings`.

Upon starting the application (Settings -> Display -> LiveWallpaper -> MyLiveWallpaper), the saved preferences need to be known so that the sprite can be displayed or not.
However, `LiveWallpaperSettings` is not instantiated until the Settings button is clicked, so `SharedPreferences` is not available, and thus saved settings are unavailable until then.

I tried this in `LiveWallpaperService.onCreateScene()`, but it has no data in it:
`SharedPreferences startupPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());`

What can I do?

Comment: you can post some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default value if the entry/sharedpref file does not exist:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean display = settings.getBoolean("display", true);
```

"public abstract boolean getBoolean (String key, boolean defValue)"

Added in API level 1
Retrieve a boolean value from the preferences.

Parameters
`key`  The name of the preference to retrieve. 
`defValue`  Value to return if this preference does not exist.

Hope I didnt misunderstood your question :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think you did misunderstand. I am not interested in a default value because there is a value that has been saved, I just can't access it when the app starts.

Comment: have you checked if a sharedpref file exist in you data/appname/shared_prefs folder?

Answer (score 0):

In your preferences xml set the default value and in your MainActivity onCreate() add the following code `setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.yourxmlname, false);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not want default values. I apologize for not being clear. In this scenario, the user has previously set a value for `displaySprite` and I am trying to retrieve this value.

Comment: The settings values are stored in the default shared preferences. You get the values by using Oli answer. Despite the name it gives you the value that the user set in the settings.

Comment: I think you (and Oli) are correct, that seems to have fixed it. Thank you.